# How to fold/accumulate a numpy matrix product (dot)?

Tags: python, numpy, fold, accumulate

With using python library numpy, it is possible to use the function [cumprod](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) to evaluate cumulative products, e.g.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,2])
np.cumprod(a)
```

gives

```
array([ 1,  2,  6, 24, 48])
```

It is indeed possible to apply this function only along one axis.

I would like to do the same with matrices (represented as numpy arrays), e.g. if I have

```
S0 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
Sx = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
Sy = np.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]])
Sz = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])
```

and

```
b = np.array([S0, Sx, Sy, Sz])
```

then I would like to have a `cumprod`-like function which gives

```
np.array([S0, S0.dot(Sx), S0.dot(Sx).dot(Sy), S0.dot(Sx).dot(Sy).dot(Sz)])
```

(This is a simple example, in reality I have potentially large matrices evaluated over n-dimensional meshgrids, so I seek for the most simple *and* efficient way to evaluate this thing.)

In e.g. Mathematica I would use

```
FoldList[Dot, IdentityMatrix[2], {S0, Sx, Sy, Sz}]
```

so I searched for a fold function, and all I found is an `accumulate` method on `numpy.ufunc`s. To be honest, I know that I am probably doomed because an attempt at

```
np.core.umath_tests.matrix_multiply.accumulate(np.array([pauli_0, pauli_x, pauli_y, pauli_z]))
```

as mentioned in [a numpy mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-December/047433.html) yields the error

```
Reduction not defined on ufunc with signature
```

Do you have an idea how to (efficiently) do this kind of calculation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `itertools.accumulate(b, func=lambda x, y: x.dot(y))`?  You'll need to import the `itertools` module.

Comment: Yes, it would work if I didn't had to carry out the accumulation along some axis of a multidimensional array.

Comment: If your matrices are large but the *number* of matrices is small, I might simply write a function with a loop and get on with your day; it takes me ~200 us to take the dot product of two 100x100 float matrices and only 1 us to execute `for i in range(100): pass`, so it's entirely possible that the function overhead will be marginal.

Comment: @GeorgSievelson: try using it in conjunction to [`apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).  It's possible that there isn't a native function to do this in numpy, but you may have to ask on the devs to be certain.

Comment: @DSM I have a lot of matrices (which I hope to keep somehow small), but I begin to fear that writing a loop will be the only sensible way to get things done. Thanks.

Comment: An earlier post in that mailing list thread cites a Cookbook page: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/MultiDot.  It's not new, and focuses on variations of the Python loop.

Comment: The Python bosses have approved a new binary operator, `@`, which might be used in `numpy` as an infix `dot`, allowing `S0 @ Sx @ Sy @ Sz`.  Not that it would speed up looping through a long string of these.

Comment: I've sketched out a possible `Cython` solution based on some work I did for `einsum`.

Answer (score 3):

As food for thought, here are 3 ways of evaluating the 3 sequential dot products:

With the normal Python reduce (which could also be written as a loop)

```
In [118]: reduce(np.dot,[S0,Sx,Sy,Sz])
array([[ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+1.j]])
```

The `einsum` equivalent

```
In [119]: np.einsum('ij,jk,kl,lm',S0,Sx,Sy,Sz)
```

The `einsum` index expression looks like a sequence of operations, but it is actually evaluated as a 5d product with summation on 3 axes.  In the C code this is done with an `nditer` and strides, but the effect is as follows:

```
In [120]: np.sum(S0[:,:,None,None,None] * Sx[None,:,:,None,None] *
    Sy[None,None,:,:,None] * Sz[None,None,None,:,:],(1,2,3))

In [127]: np.prod([S0[:,:,None,None,None], Sx[None,:,:,None,None],
    Sy[None,None,:,:,None], Sz[None,None,None,:,:]]).sum((1,2,3))
```

---

A while back while creating a patch from `np.einsum` I translated that `C` code to `Python`, and also wrote a `Cython` sum-of-products function(s).  This code is on github at

https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum

`einsum_py.py` is the Python einsum, with some useful debugging output

`sop.pyx` is the Cython code, which is compiled to `sop.so`.

Here's how it could be used for part of your problem.  I'm skipping the `Sy` array since my `sop` is not coded for complex numbers (but that could be changed).

```
import numpy as np
import sop
import einsum_py    

S0 = np.array([[1., 0], [0, 1]])
Sx = np.array([[0., 1], [1, 0]])
Sz = np.array([[1., 0], [0, -1]])

print np.einsum('ij,jk,kl', S0, Sx, Sz)
# [[ 0. -1.] [ 1.  0.]]
# same thing, but with parsing information
einsum_py.myeinsum('ij,jk,kl', S0, Sx, Sz, debug=True)
"""
{'max_label': 108, 'min_label': 105, 'nop': 3, 
 'shapes': [(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)], 
 'strides': [(16, 8), (16, 8), (16, 8)], 
 'ndim_broadcast': 0, 'ndims': [2, 2, 2], 'num_labels': 4,
 ....
 op_axes [[0, -1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, -1, 0], [0, 1, -1, -1]]
"""    

# take op_axes (for np.nditer) from this debug output
op_axes = [[0, -1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, -1, 0], [0, 1, -1, -1]]
w = sop.sum_product_cy3([S0,Sx,Sz], op_axes)
print w
```

As written `sum_product_cy3` cannot take an arbitrary number of `ops`.  Plus the iteration space increases with each op and index.  But I can imagine calling it repeatedly, either at the Cython level, or from Python.  I think it has potential for being faster than `repeat(dot...)` for lots of small arrays.

A condensed version of the Cython code is:

```
def sum_product_cy3(ops, op_axes, order='K'):
    #(arr, axis=None, out=None):
    cdef np.ndarray[double] x, y, z, w
    cdef int size, nop
    nop = len(ops)
    ops.append(None)
    flags = ['reduce_ok','buffered', 'external_loop'...]
    op_flags = [['readonly']]*nop + [['allocate','readwrite']]

    it = np.nditer(ops, flags, op_flags, op_axes=op_axes, order=order)
    it.operands[nop][...] = 0
    it.reset()
    for x, y, z, w in it:
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
           w[i] = w[i] + x[i] * y[i] * z[i]
    return it.operands[nop]
```