# using numpy's cumprod functionality with matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, homogenous-transformation

I'm trying to use the functionality of numpy's cumprod, but for matrices.
Having a matrix filled with homogeneous transformations (here random for simplicity) I want to accumulate the transformations using numpy's matrix multiplication.

```
n = 1000
data = np.random([n, 4,4])
dataAcc = cumProd(data, np.matmul)
```

dataAcc should contain the following:

```
dataAcc[0,:,:] = data[0,:,:]
dataAcc[1,:,:] = data[0,:,:] @ data[1,:,:] = dataAcc[0,:,:] @ data[1,:,:]
dataAcc[2,:,:] = dataAcc[1,:,:] @ data[2,:,:]
...
```

Is there a way to do this using fast numpy functions or some equivalent?
I do not want to use loops...

Cheers

Comment: Duplicate with no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492474/cumulative-dot-product-with-numpy

Comment: Another unanswered dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512885/cumulative-result-of-matrix-multiplications

Comment: One more, with an answer, but the discussion appears to focus on having just four matrices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993153/how-to-fold-accumulate-a-numpy-matrix-product-dot

Comment: I added an answer over in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492474/cumulative-dot-product-with-numpy